# pion/webrtc: forward live stream h264 to pion/webrtc and play in browser, the stream play abnormally。

Tags: go, webrtc, h.264, rtp

I am trying to implement forwarding live stream to webrtc for playing in browser.
Work is based on project: https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server, and webrtc use the library "pion/webrtc"
below my code for write h264 nalus sample to webrtc,

1. pull h264 data from ringbuffer
2. write h264 nalus to webrtc video track

```golang
    func (c *webrtcSession) runRead(ctx context.Context) error {
        c.ringBuffer, _ = ringbuffer.New(uint64(c.readBufferCount))
        h264FrameDuration := time.Millisecond * 33
        for {
            item, ok := c.ringBuffer.Pull()
            data := item.(*data)
            if c.videoTrack != nil && data.trackID == c.videoTrackID 
            {
                if data.h264NALUs == nil {
                    continue
                }
                outBuf := []byte{}
                for _, nalu := range data.h264NALUs {
                    outBuf = append(outBuf, []byte{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01}...)
                    outBuf = append(outBuf, nalu...)
                }
                c.videoTrack.WriteSample(media.Sample{Data: outBuf, Duration:time.Duration(h264FrameDuration)})
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the screen recording for the problem while I play in browser:https://youtu.be/twyiU9rF8AY